# Perl remove characters from string matrix according to pattern

Tags: regex, string, perl, matrix

I have multiple strings with the same length stored in a hash data structure. **Example:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'first' => 'abcXY',
          'second' => 'XYXYa',
          'third' => '*abXZ'
        };
```

From this 'matrix' of characters, I would like to remove the 'columns' which exclusively contain the characters `X` or `Y`. In the above example, this would be the fourth character of each string (4th 'column'). 
The desired result would be:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'first' => 'abcY',
          'second' => 'XYXa',
          'third' => '*abZ'
        };
```

Following code does this by creating a transpose of the values of my hash structure and then determines which indices to keep:

```
# data structure
my %h = ('first'=>'abcXY', 'second'=>'XYXYa', 'third'=>'*abXZ' );

# get length of all values in hash
my $nchar = length $h{(keys(%h))[0]};

# transpose values of hash
my @transposed = map { my $idx=$_; [map {substr ($_, $idx, 1) } values(%h)]  } 0..$nchar-1; 

# determine indices which I want to keep
my @indices;
for my $i (0..$#transposed){
        my @a = @{$transposed[$i]};

        # do not keep index if column consists of X and Y
        if ( scalar(grep {/X|Y/} @a) < scalar(@a) ) {
                push @indices, $i;
        }   
}

# only keep letters with indices
for my $k (keys %h){
        my $str = $h{$k};
        my $reduced = join "", map{ substr ($str, $_, 1) } @indices;
        $h{$k} = $reduced;
}
```

This is a terrible amount of code for such a simple operation. How could I do this more elegantly (preferably not with some matrix library, but with standard perl)?

**Edit**

Here another example: From the following strings, the first and last characters should be removed, because in both strings, the first and last position is either `X` or `Y`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 'Xsome_strX',
          '2' => 'YsomeXstrY'
        };
```

Desired result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 'some_str',
          '2' => 'someXstr'
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $total = values %hash;
my %ind;
for my $v (values %hash) {

  $ind{ pos($v) -1 }++ while $v =~ /[XY]/g;
}
my @to_remove = sort {$b <=> $a} grep { $ind{$_} == $total } keys %ind;

for my $v (values %hash) {

  substr($v, $_, 1, "") for @to_remove;
}
```

Comment: But this assumes that I know that it's the fourth column I want to remove. The above was just an example. I want to find all columns that only contain either `X` or `Y` and remove these columns.

Comment: added another example @Сухой27

Comment: This does not work for me,  @Сухой27: I am getting a `Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-)`...

Comment: It is `my %hash = ('1'=>'Xsome_strX', '2'=>'YsomeXstrY');`